# Django: is not a valid view function or pattern name when trying to add a url using url tag in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

i want to add a url to my project that would get the id of a video and append it to url like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/course/learn-angular/contents/?lecture=1` `<a href="?lecture={{v.serial_number}}"` instead of the regular django `{% url '?lecture={{v.serial_number}}' %}`.

when i do this `<a href="{% url '?lecture={{v.serial_number}}' %}">` that is when i get this error `Reverse for '?lecture={{v.serial_number}}' not found. '?lecture={{v.serial_number}}' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`.

NOTE: when i add the url as `?lecture={{v.serial_number}}` is show this error when i click on the url `Page not found (404) Directory indexes are not allowed here` and all these are happening i think becuase i have this line `<base href="{% static '/' %}">` in my **base.html** where i am extending all my static files from.

And if you asking why i have this line `base href="{% static '/' %}">`, it's becuase my static files are not loading up as usual, it keep showing a ***MIME type not supoorted error, refused to apply 127.0.0.1:8000/assets/css/style.css*** so the only way i could fix this was to add that line to my base.html.

Back to the main question, what is the right way to write tihs url  withot getting this error `Page not found (404) Directory indexes are not allowed here.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the url name for the urlpattern that matches `/course/learn-angular/contents/` and then pass in the query params for the lecture id `?lecture=1`

```
<a href="{% url 'name_for_route' %}?lecture={{v.serial_number}}">
```